# Fortran77 write(0,*) DLL command not flushing to R GUI console

Tags: r, fortran, fortran77

I have a Fortran77 source code with lots of printing commands of the form:

write( **fileID**, label ) somevariable

This F77 code is compiled via "R CMD SHLIB code.f" into a DLL which is called from R. If within the F77 code fileID is a regular text file, the command works fine. However, in case for the standard console output,
that is  **fileID = 0** , R creates a "fort.0" temporary file, instead of showing the output within the R GUI console window.

This problem occurs only in my Windows 64bit version. Under Linux 32bit and 64bit, the output for **fileID = 0** gets correctly shown in the console.

I already tried the flush.console() command. No success.

Does maybe anybody know how to resolve that issue? Re-writing the write(0,*) commands from F77 in R is unfortunately not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use native print methods in extension modules loaded into R.  [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) has this to say:

> ### 6.5.1 Printing from FORTRAN
>
> On many systems FORTRAN 'write' and 'print' statements can be used,
>   but the output may not interleave well with that of C, and will be
>   invisible on GUI interfaces.  They are not portable and best avoided.
>
> Three subroutines are provided to ease the output of information
>   from FORTRAN code.
>
> ```
>  subroutine dblepr(LABEL, NCHAR, DATA, NDATA)
>  subroutine realpr(LABEL, NCHAR, DATA, NDATA)
>  subroutine intpr (LABEL, NCHAR, DATA, NDATA)
> ```
>
> Here LABEL is a character label of up to 255 characters, NCHAR is its
>   length (which can be '-1' if the whole label is to be used), and DATA
>   is an array of length at least NDATA of the appropriate type ('double
>   precision', 'real' and 'integer' respectively).  These routines print
>   the label on one line and then print DATA as if it were an R vector on
>   subsequent line(s).  They work with zero NDATA, and so can be used to
>   print a label alone.

I know the C/C++ side much better and there we surely have to use `Rprintf()` et al in order to have the output cooperate nicely with R's own output stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dirk! So basically I am just lucky, that it works under Linux. But have no chance to make it bullet proof under Windows GUI.
I do have the option to switch from F77 to plain C (via f2c translation). In C I could simply replace all "fprintf()" by "Rprintf()".
Do you think that might work?

Comment: For a real Fortran solution, probably worth a r-devel post, or see if a real Fortran programmer pipes in. I don't even play one on TV ...  For the C side, definitely -- some people also play with macros. I replaced as you suggest, and `Rprintf()` and `REprintf()` work just fine.

Comment: Thanks again, Dirk! I will then give the C version a try, this might be the simplest option.
A shame though, as under Linux the "write(0,*)" works flawless with the console stream.